# Custom attribute jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need create a custom attribute for my datatables instance, and  I need keep this value, ex:

When I create an instance:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    //common attributes
    ajax: 'url.json',
    columns: [...],
    //custom attribute
    hasSomeValueHere: 'helloword'
});
```

and I would like to keep it on settings of datatable, so if I check it will be there:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    //common attributes
    ...
    fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings){
        alert(oSettings.hasSomeValueHere); //helloword
    }
});
```

There any way to extends datatable this way?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using datatables with client side data or do you need to send parameters to the server?

Comment: Hmmm, no I don't need to send this params to the server, because I've already keep some values in localstorage as sortColumn, searchValue, page, pagesize... But, now I need keep a custom attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to extend dataTables for that. `oSettings` has an object, `oInit`, that holds the entire initialisation object, i.e the dataTables options. Example :

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
    hasSomeValueHere: 'helloworld',
    fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings){
        alert(oSettings.oInit.hasSomeValueHere); //helloworld
    }
});
```

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bvr2jk8z/**

---

This works in 1.10.x as well, using `DataTable()`

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    hasSomeValueHere: 'helloworld',
    drawCallback: function(settings){
        alert(settings.oInit.hasSomeValueHere); //helloworld
    }
});
```

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fkbtv1x7/**

Comment: I was trying to get the from from "settings.oApi.hasSomeValue"... I'm so noob! =)